# WPF Draw a line from a label to a selected item in a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am making a matching item user control.

On the left I have a Label that is bound to the value the user is trying to match.

On the right I have a ListVIew populated with possible matches for the value on the left.

After the user selects the match in the list I want to draw a line from the label to the selected ListView Item that will also update when the list is scrolled.

I don't know how to get positions and draw the line. Any ideas?

```
        <Canvas Name="ConnectionCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Background="Red">
        <Grid Name="ConnectionGrid" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ConnectionCanvas}" 
              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ConnectionCanvas}">
            <Label Name="SourceLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Content="{Binding ValueToMatch}"/>
            <ListView Name="DestinationList" Margin="5" Width="300" SelectionMode="Single"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                      
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleMatchLookupCollection}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="Identifier" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedMatch}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      userControls:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"                  
                      userControls:GridViewSort.SortGlyphAscending="pack://application:,,,/Divestco.Windows.Resources;component/PNGs/General/Small/UpArrow.png"
                      userControls:GridViewSort.SortGlyphDescending="pack://application:,,,/Divestco.Windows.Resources;component/PNGs/General/Small/DownArrow.png">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:ListViewGridViewColumnAutoWidthBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=FirstColumnDisplayName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstColumnValue}"  userControls:GridViewSort.PropertyName="FirstColumnValue" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=SecondColumnDisplayName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SecondColumnValue}"  userControls:GridViewSort.PropertyName="SecondColumnValue" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ThirdColumnDisplayName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ThirdColumnValue}"  userControls:GridViewSort.PropertyName="ThirdColumnValue" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <Line Name="ConnectorLine" Stroke="Black" />
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
private void HandleSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Point relativeLefttPoint = SourceLabel.TransformToAncestor(ConnectionGrid)
      .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    UIElement selectedContainer = (UIElement)DestinationList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(DestinationList.SelectedIndex);
    Point relativeRightPoint = default(Point);
    if (selectedContainer != null)
    {
         relativeRightPoint =
            selectedContainer.TranslatePoint(new Point(selectedContainer.DesiredSize.Width, 0.0), ConnectionGrid);
    }

    ConnectorLine.X1 = relativeLefttPoint.X;
    ConnectorLine.X2 = relativeLefttPoint.Y;
    ConnectorLine.Y1 = relativeRightPoint.X;
    ConnectorLine.Y2 = relativeRightPoint.Y;
}
```

Comment: For drawing line, you could for example made transparent canvas over whole window, and draw on it line, with one point Canvas.Left/top pointing the label, and second point(calculated from SekectionChanged/scrolled). You could also use polyline for more complex lines, or even path, but the last one isn't easy in use :P) on scrolling you could use e.delta for fast change. Just make sure that selectedItem is still visible :d